# How to build a nested comment system in django without django-mptt or any other library?

Tags: python, django

I'm working a blog in django and want to build a nested comment system but I don't want to use any library to achieve it.i want to know how big companies like instagram build comment section in python .
I feel like I'm only learning to use libraries  not learning to code.

Comment: So try installing library and look into the source code. It's good that you want to learn and reverse engineering source code is one of the best methods to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly about how you set up your models. A minimal case to build a branching comment tree would look something like this:

```
class Comment:

    text = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Comment', default=None)
```

Comment: Oh can you please tell me your approach to build nested comments?

Comment: I'm happy to help with specific questions. I've given you a good start.